# select filter records from table using jpa entity manager

Tags: java, sql, jpa, ejb

i want to find entiries in table with filter conditions as below using jpa enity manager

```
select * from My_Table where (status='A' or status='Z' or status='NA')
```

please suggest a way to do this..

Comment: Check `EntityManager` docs. It has a `createQuery` method. And then look into `Query` class, which has various methods like `getResultList()` which will give you all the matching records.

Comment: just curiosity, did you make any effort and check at least one jpa tutorial?

Comment: @user902383. I can bet he didn't even type the title on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the following:

1. em = EntityManager
2. MyTable = My_Table entity
3. MyTable has a status field.

**Java**

```
public List findByStatus() {
    return em.createQuery(
        "SELECT mt FROM MyTable mt WHERE mt.status in ('A', 'Z', 'NA')")
        .getResultList();
}
```